# Prove $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}\cos(\frac{x}{n})$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, solution-verification

This proof is done in the context of an analysis course (i.e. no calculus 'tests' can be used).

Proof:

$\cos(\frac{x}{n}) \le M$ for some $x,M \in \mathbb{R} \text{ } \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, as the cosine function is bounded.

Then we have that $$|\frac{1}{n^2}\cos(\frac{x}{n})| \le |\frac{1}{n^2}M|$$
The sequence given by $|\frac{1}{n^2}M|$ defines a sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|\frac{1}{n^2}M|$ that clearly exists (it is a multiple of a $p$ series with $p>1$).
Because the sequence of this sum bounds the original sequence (as above) and the sum of this sequence exists, then so must $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\frac{1}{n^2}\cos(\frac{x}{n})|$. The sum in question converges absolutely and therefore converges 'normally'. Hence the sum in the title converges.

Comment: This is fine. What is the question?

Comment: Everything is correct, though phrase "$|\cos x/n|\leq M$ for some $M\in\mathbb{R}$" sounds a bit weird to me.

Comment: The minimum $M$ that is valid for any $x$ is $M=1$